# JQuery + Ajax - how to clear results section with reset button?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

I'm learning Jquery and stumbled upon the issue I cannot bypass.
In the following example that I've got from the internet I have JSP form (simple addition calculator) and Servlet that adds two numbers together and returns the result when pressing "Calculate" button.

My problem that I can't find a way on how to clear JSP result section after pressing "Reset" button. The section I'm talking about is this: `<div id="result"></div>` at the end of JSP file.

JSP:

```
    <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Ajax Example in JSP And Servlet</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#btn').click(function() {

  var data = $('#xForm').serializeArray();


 $.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   url:"CalcAjax",
   data:data,
   cache: false,
   success:function(msg)
   {
    $("#result").hide();
    $("#result").html("Addition Value is: " + msg + " ").fadeIn("slow");
   }
  });

 });
});
</script>


</head>
<body>
<form id="xForm" method="post" ACTION="/CalcAjax">
 Enter number1:
 <input id="number" type="text" name="number" />
 Enter number2:
 <input id="number1" type="text" name="number1" />
 <input id="btn" type="button" value="Calculate" name="btn"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <input id="reset" type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset"/>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Servlet:

```
package com.test;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class CalcAjax extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

String redir="";
String urlencode=""; 

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  try { 
            redir=("/ajax.jsp");
            urlencode = response.encodeRedirectURL(redir.toString());
            response.sendRedirect(urlencode);

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher4 = request.getRequestDispatcher("/ajax.jsp");
            dispatcher4.forward(request, response);
        } 
}
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int number = 0,number1=0;

    number = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("number"));
    number1 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("number1"));

    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    out.println(number+number1+" <br>");

 }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can be done with a simple `click()` function:

```
$("#reset").click(function(){
  $("#result").empty();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#reset").on("click", function(e) {
    $("#result").empty();
});
```